# How to populate a form: database record using onclick image

Tags: mysql, forms, image, onclick

This is my selector:

```html
<div class="text-center col-lg-6"><h4><strong><FONT COLOR="red">choose the color of your new shoes:</FONT></strong></h4>
    
<input type="image" src="https://glarza.com/img/black-shoes.webp" name="color" value="1" onclick="...">
    

<input type="image"src="https://glarza.com/img/red-shoes.webp" name="color" value="2"  onclick="...">
    
</div>
```

Database: id:1  BLACK ...
id: 2 RED ...

This is my form:

```html
<form action="https://glarza.com/color.php" class="omb_loginForm" autocomplete="off" method="POST" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">

<div class="input-group col-lg-12">
<span class="input-group-addon">Color..<i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="color" placeholder="color" />
</div>
```

How to populate the color input inside my form ?
Please if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You should change your input type to radio.
After the user selected a radio button you detect the input change and submit the form with js.

Css code for the image radio group:

```
/* HIDE RADIO */
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* IMAGE STYLES */
[type=radio] + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* CHECKED STYLES */
[type=radio]:checked + img {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

HTML for the radio image input group:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/0bf/fff&text=A">
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="black">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x60/b0f/fff&text=B">
</label>
```

Submit the form on radio group change:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=color]').change(function() {
 document.forms[myFormName].submit()
});
```